# Lattice divisors of 165, ordered by divisibility. Draw Hasse diagram, get complements, check if distributive, check if Boolean.

Tags: abstract-algebra, divisibility, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

I have the following exercise:

Having the lattice $D_{165}$ of the divisors of 165, ordered by divisibility

1) Draw Hasse Diagram;
2) Find all complements;
3) Check if it's a distributive lattice;
4) Check if it's a Boolean lattice.

My development:

The divisors of 165 are $D_{165} = \left \{ 1,3,5,11,15,33,55,165 \right \}$

1)
this is the diagram I have done, look at the figure on the left:
[image: lattice D_165]

2)
in this table I have put an asterisk when an element has its complement.
i.e. every time is true this condition $\forall a \in D_{165}$
$a \land a' = 0 \quad \mbox{ and } \quad a \lor a' = 1$
\begin{array}{c|c}    
\, & 1 & 3 & 5 & 11 & 15 & 33 & 55 & 165 \\     
\hline    1 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & * \\    
\hline    3 & - & - & - & - & - & - & * & - \\    
\hline    5 & - & - & - & - & - & * & - & - \\    
\hline    11 & - & - & - & - & * & - & - & - \\    
\hline    15 & - & - & - & * & - & - & - & - \\    
\hline    33 & - & - & * & - & - & - & - & - \\    
\hline    55 & - & * & - & - & - & - & - & - \\    
\hline    165 & * & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\   
\end{array}
so this lattice is NOT a Complemented lattice.

3)
it is NOT possible to get a sublattice like one of the two nondistributive lattices on the right in the previous image.
So the lattice $D_{165}$ is distributive.

4)
Since NOT all elements in the lattice have a complement, i.e. it is not a Complemented lattice. The lattice $D_{165}$ is not a Boolean lattice.

Please, can you tell me if the exercise is correct?  Can you give me any suggestion?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By re-arranging the elements of the Hasse diagram, you can check that it's isomorphic to the 8 elements Boolean lattice (aka, [the cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure))).
So it is indeed complemented, and I suppose it answers all of your queries.

---

By the way, in the same page I put a link above, in the section examples, you can see that whenever $n$ is a square-free number, as it is the case of $165$, the lattice of divisors is Boolean.
Clearly this is a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: Still I'm not convinced that my lattice $D_{164}$ is complemented. For example, if you look to my Hasse diagram, see 33 and 165: $33 \land 165 = 165 \land 33 = 33 \ne 0, \quad \mbox{ and } \quad 33 \lor 165 = 165 \lor 33 = 165 = 1$. or is it wrong?

Comment: @JB-Franco: here's the complements. $1'=165$, $3'=55$, $5'=33$, $11'=15$, and the other follow by symmetry. More generally, for the lattice of divisors of a square-free integer $n$, we have $m' = n/m$. I don't understand why you picked those meets and joins...

Comment: Ok! So I have calculated the right complements for each element, and my table is right! And therefore my lattice is complemented and is a Boolean Algebra!

Comment: @JB-Franco By the way, in the link I send in my answer, the cube (of which your lattice is an instance) is in the beginning of the page, on the right, under the name "Boolean lattice of subsets"

Comment: @JB-Franco. Yes, that's what I said: it is a Boolean lattice. Therefore, with the complementation it forms a Boolean algebra.

Comment: Yes! In my head I was wrongly convinced that every element must be comlement with every element! Your answer has been useful! Are the other points of the exercise right?

Comment: @JB-Franco, once it is a Boolean lattice, it is distributive (as you had already concluded) and complemented. You have the complements and the Hasse diagram (consider the re-arranged form in the link I gave, but the one in yours it's ok). It seems like you have everything. By the way you can forget about that table.

Comment: Rearranging the elements in my Hasse diagram in the way as in the cube, is it enough to prove that there is an isomorphism?

Comment: @JB-Franco, yes, because the cube is a Boolean lattice, as it is said in that page. If a lattice has the same Hasse diagram as another lattice, then they are isomorphic (the isomorphism is just a re-labelling of the elements).